# SwiftUI - Transition animation bug (Resolved: not a bug!)

Tags: animation, swiftui

This is a follow up to a prior question which was solved then unsolved.

The situation is that I have a grid of text on a screen that is presented via a transition from another view. I can't use `LazyVGrid` to present the grid because the width of one column needs to match the longest text in it. So the solution I have is to use `HStack`s and set the width of the column. To set that width as the width of the longest text I'm using a `GeometryReader` to read the size of the text and then sending that information via a `anchorPreference` up the view tree to a `@State` variable that's used to set the width of all the labels in the column.

It sounds complicated but it works. At least ... until I tried to transition to it. Then an old bug returned where the use of the `anchorPreference` and `onPreferenceChange(...)` function seem to change the animations bringing on the view and cause the text to slide on too fast. As per this screen capture:

[image: Bug screen shot]

At the moment I'm at a loss as to how to correct the animations so the text slides on with the parent view. Any suggestions?

Here is the complete code for this bug:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TransitionAnimationBug: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var displaySettings = false

    var body: some View {

        Group {
            if displaySettings {
                DataView(displaySettings: $displaySettings)
                    .transition(.slide)
            } else {
                MainView(displaySettings: $displaySettings)
                    .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: displaySettings)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {

    let displaySettings: Binding<Bool>

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Button("Show transition bug") {
                displaySettings.wrappedValue.toggle()
            }
            Text("Watch the text as it animates on. it should slide with the view, but instead moves around independently.")
                .padding(20).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Text("This bug is triggered by the label width update via a @State variable in the onPreferenceChange function.")
                .padding(20).multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
    }
}

// The preference key used to advise the parent view of a label's width.
struct LabelWidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = 0.0
    static func reduce(value: inout Double, nextValue: () -> Double) {
        if value != nextValue() {
            value = max(value, nextValue())
        }
    }
}

struct DataView: View {

    let displaySettings: Binding<Bool>
    @State private var labelWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            row(title: "Short title", desc: "Short title long description")
            row(title: "Rather long title", desc: "Rather long title long description")
            row(title: "SS", desc: "Super short text")
            Button("Close") { displaySettings.wrappedValue.toggle() }
        }
        .onPreferenceChange(LabelWidthPreferenceKey.self) {
            // Updating the label width here triggers the bug.
            if $0 != labelWidth {
                labelWidth = $0
            }
        }
    }

    private func row(title: String, desc: String) -> some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(title)
                    .frame(minWidth: labelWidth, alignment: .leading)
                    .border(.red)
                    .anchorPreference(key: LabelWidthPreferenceKey.self, value: .bounds) {
                        geometry[$0].width.rounded(.up)
                    }
                Text(desc)
                    .border(.red)
            }
        }
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 20)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a SwiftUI bug. Find below a fix (tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4)

```
    VStack(spacing: 30) {
        row(title: "Short title", desc: "Short title long description")
        row(title: "Rather long title", desc: "Rather long title long description")
        row(title: "SS", desc: "Super short text")
        Button("Close") { displaySettings.wrappedValue.toggle() }
    }
    .animation(nil, value: labelWidth)                     // << here !!
    .onPreferenceChange(LabelWidthPreferenceKey.self) {
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that. I'd messed with turning off animations but obviously not got it right because when I did it the text just appeared on screen rather than animated. Are you able to describe how this works in more detail?

Comment: Any changes in view after activation of corresponding animation value is handled as animatable. In this flow used GeometryReader's geometry is changed during animation so internal dependent frames (calculable) also changed so animated. So we need explicitly disable animation for that calculable subview (it is calculated only on initial layout and will be re-calculated if some internals changed, eg. strings)

Comment: Cool. I see what you're talking about. Still does my head in a bit but that's the fun of learning a whole new set of technologies.